# Convert XML having multiple lines in a node to SQL as diffrent fields

Tags: xml, t-sql, parsing, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an XML files which contains multiple nodes with line breaks. Need to insert it into address table as line 1, line 2 etc 
For example:

```
<AddressEntry>
    <AddressData>
      abc, xyz
      (MALE)
      DOB: 11/11/1994
      1230 Newbury Road #167
      Newbury Park, CA 91120
      (801) 119-0839
    </AddressData>  
    <AddressData>
      <!-- more of them -->
    </AddressData>  
</AddressEntry>
```

where I need to get First Name (abc) and last name (xyz) inserted into 2 colums, next line as gender, next line to DOB (11/11/1994 by taking only value, cutting DOB:), next line to line 1, next to Line2/State/ZIP by splitting using space in the line and insert it into SQL table

Comment: It is impossible to help you here... You must add some more details: Which RDBMS (incl. version). The tag `[sql]` is not enough... Are there more than one `<AddressData>` elements in one `<AddressEntry>`? Is the structure always the same? Might there be missing lines or would a missing line show up as an empty line? Might there be additional lines? Best was a [mcve] with DDL and INSERT and the expected output. And show your own attempt. This helps more than many lines of explanations...

Comment: Thank you Shungo for responding. To your question, Yes there will be multiple <AddressData> entity with in <AddressEntry>, and the structure will be the same. I want to parse the xml and insert it into my table in SQL 2008 R2

Comment: Okay, next time please use the [edit] option to work this straight into your question, thx

Answer (score 0):

This is a really awful format you have to deal with... If this is under your control, you really should change this to something more structured. Nevertheless this can be done with something along these lines:

I set up a *mockup-table* (next time please do this yourself):

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourXml XML);
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES
('<AddressEntry>
    <AddressData>
      abc, xyz
      (MALE)
      DOB: 11/11/1994
      1230 Newbury Road #167
      Newbury Park, CA 91120
      (801) 119-0839
    </AddressData>
</AddressEntry>')
,(('<AddressEntry>
    <AddressData>
      Tom, Jones
      (MALE)
      DOB: 11/11/2000
      1230 Newbury Road #167
      Newbury Park, CA 91120
      (801) 119-0839
    </AddressData>
        <AddressData>
      Jessica, Maryland
      (FEMALE)
      DOB: 11/11/2002
      1230 Newbury Road #167
      Newbury Park, CA 91120
      (801) 119-0839
    </AddressData>
</AddressEntry>'));
```

--This is the query

```
SELECT ID
      ,E.NameParts.value('/x[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS FirstName 
      ,E.NameParts.value('/x[2]','nvarchar(max)') AS LastName 
      ,D.SexLine AS PersonSex
      ,CONVERT(DATE,SUBSTRING(D.DOBLine,5,20),101) AS DOB      --relying on a dateformat mm/dd/yyyy (type 101)
      ,D.Addr1Line
      ,D.Addr2Line
      ,D.PhoneLine
FROM @mockupTable t
CROSS APPLY t.YourXml.nodes('/AddressEntry/AddressData') A(addrDat)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(A.addrDat.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),CHAR(13),CHAR(10)),CHAR(10)+CHAR(10),CHAR(10))) B(AdressText)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT B.AdressText AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),CHAR(10),'</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) C(SplittedInParts)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT 
                 LTRIM(RTRIM(SplittedInParts.value('/x[2]','nvarchar(max)'))) AS NameLine
                ,LTRIM(RTRIM(SplittedInParts.value('/x[3]','nvarchar(max)'))) AS SexLine
                ,LTRIM(RTRIM(SplittedInParts.value('/x[4]','nvarchar(max)'))) AS DOBLine
                ,LTRIM(RTRIM(SplittedInParts.value('/x[5]','nvarchar(max)'))) AS Addr1Line
                ,LTRIM(RTRIM(SplittedInParts.value('/x[6]','nvarchar(max)'))) AS Addr2Line
                ,LTRIM(RTRIM(SplittedInParts.value('/x[7]','nvarchar(max)'))) AS PhoneLine
           ) D
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT D.NameLine AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) E(NameParts);
```

The result

```
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+------------------------+------------------------+----------------+
| ID | FirstName | LastName | PersonSex | DOB        | Addr1Line              | Addr2Line              | PhoneLine      |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+------------------------+------------------------+----------------+
| 1  | abc       | xyz      | (MALE)    | 1994-11-11 | 1230 Newbury Road #167 | Newbury Park, CA 91120 | (801) 119-0839 |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+------------------------+------------------------+----------------+
| 2  | Tom       | Jones    | (MALE)    | 2000-11-11 | 1230 Newbury Road #167 | Newbury Park, CA 91120 | (801) 119-0839 |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+------------------------+------------------------+----------------+
| 2  | Jessica   | Maryland | (FEMALE)  | 2002-11-11 | 1230 Newbury Road #167 | Newbury Park, CA 91120 | (801) 119-0839 |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+------------------------+------------------------+----------------+
```

Some explanation:

all the `CROSS APPLY` lines will do some *row-wise* computation

- First of all we fetch the strings within the XML.
- We have to be sure, that the various kinds of linebreaks won't disturb (see the steps with `CHAR()`)
- Split the string in its lines
- return each line separately
- Split the name line

The list after `SELECT`

- The final select will retrieve the name parts and deal with the DOB

Be warned: Such formats always tend to be somehow dirty and might mess this up...